# Get rid of Injectable attribute in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

We would like to reuse some code in two projects, one is implemented with knockout, the other with angular2. Is there a chance, that you can get rid of the Injectable attribute in angular2?

I couldn't find any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say `@Injectable()` is required when the constructor has dependencies (parameters).

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/InjectableMetadata-class.html

> Injector will throw NoAnnotationError when trying to instantiate a class that does not have @Injectable marker, as shown in the example below.

**A workaround** would be to register all providers with dependencies as factories, then you don't need `@Injectable()`

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [OtherProviders, SomeDep,
    provide(MyClass, { useFactory: (dep1) => { return MyClass(dep1); },
                  deps: [SomeDep] })
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Provider-class.html (search for `useFactory`)

Answer (score 0):

`@Injectable` is a decorator that is responsible to wrap the instance to be able to find out its dependencies and provides them within its constructor. If you don't have the injectable decorator, you need to instantiate things by your own and provide what it expects at its constructor level.

I think that this github issue could help you to understand what `@Injectable` actually does:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4404